# How to make POST Form call in php + json

Tags: php, python, json, curl, post

I want to make a POST call from PHP to my python API

here is the equivalent in Python:

```
import requests
import json
payload = json.dumps({'serviceID':'131001086184'})
r = requests.post('http://17.../todo/api/line/v1.0/tasks', data=dict(data=payload))
print r.content
```

Works like a charm.

Here the equivalent in curl:

```
curl -i -F data='{"serviceID":"131001086184"}' http://17.../todo/api/line/v1.0/tasks
```

Works too.

Now PHP:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://17.../todo/api/line/v1.0/tasks';
$postData = array('serviceID' => '131001086184');
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => "Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
        'content' => json_encode($postData)
    )
));

$response = file_get_contents($url. FALSE. &context)
$responseData = json_decode($response, TRUE);
echo $responseData['published'];
?>
```

Does not work and I dont get error message. 
What am I missing?

Comment: `var_dump($response); exit;` What does that give you?

Comment: Is that your real code? If so, you have a typo in your `file_get_contents()`, you are concatenating variables instead of sending 3 parameters; you need commas.

Answer (score -1):

In your code `$response = file_get_contents($url. FALSE. &context)`
You are concatenating $url with FALSE and &context,

Use the following:-

```
 $response = file_get_contents($url, FALSE, &context);
```

Comment: that doesnt change the outcome